# How to remove <div form-group> yii2

Tags: html, yii2

I need to this HTML

```
<div class="input-group form-control">
 <input type="text" placeholder="От">
  <span>-</span>
 <input type="text" placeholder="До">
</div>
```

But my yii2 code do this HTML

```
 <div class="input-group form-control">
  <div class="form-group field-clientsobjecttype-0-price_from">
   <input type="text" placeholder="От" name="ClientsObjectType[0][price_to]">
  </div>
  <span>-</span>
  <div class="form-group field-clientsobjecttype-0-price_to">
   <input type="text" placeholder="До" name="ClientsObjectType[0][price_to]">
  </div>
 </div>
```

How to remove this wrapper - `<div class="form-group field-clientsobjecttype-0-price_from">` ??
This is my view

```
<div class="input-group form-control">
<?= $form->field($objects, "[{$i}]price_from", ['template' =>'<input type="text" placeholder="От" name="ClientsObjectType[0][price_to]">'])->textInput([])->label(false); ?>
<span>-</span>
<?= $form->field($objects, "[{$i}]price_to", ['template' =>'<input type="text" placeholder="До" name="ClientsObjectType[0][price_to]">'])->textInput([])->label(false); ?>
</div>
```

So, how I can fix this problem ??

Comment: I would first ask, why do you need to remove those divs?

Comment: I need this for my css template. I can`t change template. So that is possible?

Comment: div.form-group contains error and hint message, so you should change css instead of html

Comment: Just like @QuyetTran said, you should modify the css on your template. Otherwise you will begin to have more conflicts with the way ActiveForm works.

Comment: **Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606834/yii-2-0-how-to-generate-form-without-div-class-form-group/27610072).** (soju) Good luck

Answer (score 8):

Try `$form->field($objects, "[{$i}]price_from", ['options' => ['tag' => false]])`

Answer (score 0):

Try $form->field($objects, "[{$i}]price_from", ['options' => ['class' => 'custom-class']])

or

Try $form->field($objects, "[{$i}]price_from", ['options' => ['tag' => false]])

[options detail](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#$options-detail)